# CSS 3D rotation, fiddle in different browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a pretty big fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/pz5VJ/3/

It has a function that is called on resizing the window to scale different things. That works fine in all browsers.

```
function dim()
```

It also has a function that rotates banners.

```
function dauerrotieren()
```

You can set the amount of banners and it will put them into the next place. I have 6 possible image, so you can set the **var anzahl_an_bannern** to an amount between 1 and 6.

The whole thing works fine in Opera and Chrome. In IE it does not work. I assume there is an issue with the CSS.

Firefox: Basically works, BUT the rotating back to 0degree (line 42) goes in a movement instead of in 0ms. I want it to imply a continuous rotation, not 4x90 and the once -360.

I cannot have it just increment by 90 degree into infinity because if you minimize the browser and ipen it again after a while it will do all those missed out rotations as quick as it can to get back to the current degree (3780 or wherever it may be at that time).

Sorry for the lengthy post. If it contains too much confusing german comments in the code I can clean it up so it is better readable, or substitute it for english. Got an appointment soon though, so I would have got to do that tomorrow.

Comment: so...what you want to do is make it IE/FF compatible?

Comment: @stackErr yes exactly ...

Answer (score 0):

in IE, preserve-3D does not work yet so you get flat surface instead 3D effect.
Here's the original text from MSDN:

"Note  The W3C specification defines a keyword value of preserve-3d for this property, which indicates that flattening is not performed. At this time, Internet Explorer 10 does not support the preserve-3d keyword. You can work around this by manually applying the parent element's transform to each of the child elements in addition to the child element's normal transform."

Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673529%28v=vs.85%29.aspx